# Error Bad operand type for binary operator '+'

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on an assignment where I need to do some work with `ArrayList`s.  I declare one `ArrayList` early on in my program as

```
static ArrayList<Double> prices = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I want to use this arraylist in an enhanced for loop in a method later on.  Currently the code I have for this method is

```
public static double getTotal(ArrayList<Double> prices) {
    double total = 0.0;
    for (double value: prices){
        total += (prices);
    }

    subTotal = total + (total * .0825); //add tax to get subTotal
    return subTotal;
}
```

I am trying to get the value total to = the total from the previous iteration + each value in the ArrayList prices.  I'm pretty sure that the way I have it programmed is not the correct way to do it, but I am totally stumped on how to get this to work.  Any ideas?  If you need further clarification on what I'm trying to do or if you need more excerpts from my code I'm happy to provide it.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you think `total += (prices);` expands to ?

Comment: Also, from the given code, `subtotal` hasn't been declared.

Comment: @sam from what we know, subtotal could be a static class variable

Answer (score 1):

```
total += value
```

You should add the value, not the List.

---

Structure of a for each :

1. For
2. Type of the objects/primitives inside the list
3. Name of the temporary copy of the variable from the list
4. :
5. Name of the list

Comment: Got rid of the error--thank you!  Would you mind explaining what makes this work?  Just a rookie here.

Comment: Well actually, when looping with this type of loop, a copy of each of the indexes is assigned to the value declared. What you want to do with this copy is make a sum in your case. That is way value was the variable to use hère.

Comment: Ah okay, so "value" represents a temp copy of the variable, sounds good!  Thanks for your help.